# Adding a UIImageView to main view from a struct

Tags: objective-c, ios, struct, uiimageview

I'm new to Obj-C and I'm looking for a little help.

I have a struct which I defined in my header file.:

```
struct EnemyBall {

    int ballnum;
    CGPoint pos;
    UIImageView *image;

} EnemyBall1,EnemyBall2;
```

Now in my ViewDidLoad method I want to add initialize the UIImageView of the struct with a .png and add it to the main view.

I tried to with this code:

```
[EnemyBall1.image initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enemyball.png"]];

CGRect frame2 = [EnemyBall1.image frame];
frame2.origin.x = 140;
frame2.origin.y = 140;
[EnemyBall1.image setFrame:frame2];
[self.view addSubview:EnemyBall1.image];
```

However, this doesn't seem to add the UIImageView to the view as I don't see it when I run the code.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your viewDidLoad called? Add an NSLog in there, also check the value of self.view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show where you allocate `EnemyBall1.image`?

```
[EnemyBall1.image initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enemyball.png"]];
```

should this not be:

```
EnemyBall1.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enemyball.png"]];
```

Comment: I don't think that is the case because EnemyBall1 is a struct not a UIView.

Also ViewDidLoad is called because my UIButtons are loaded.